# SharePoint online list rollup options

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

I am using SharePoint Online, I have site with several sub sites. each sub site has a list. All lists are using same content type. I need to rollup data from all sub sites. I dont want to use content search web part. I know that rollup can be achieved through content query web part and i can modify xslt to display multiple columns. But i want to display view in table format with sorting/filtering. Sorting and Filtering is Important.

Also please let me know if there is any other way to achieve rollup in SharePoint Online. 
I looked into some third part tools like lightningtools/bamboosolutions but these are very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

To rollup data from all sub sites, we can add and edit the data view web part in SharePoint designer.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

[Using a Data View Web Part to create a cross-site lists rollup view (Office 365 SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2010).](https://zioed.wordpress.com/2011/10/24/using-a-data-view-web-part-to-create-a-cross-site-lists-rollup-view-office-365-sharepoint-online-and-sharepoint-2010/)

[List Aggregation-Rollup across site collections (Even across Farms) using Dataview, Web Services in SharePoint.](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2010/10/list-rollup-across-sitecollections-using-webservices-dataview.html)

Answer (score 0):

If modern is an option then the PnP Search web parts will provide both filtrering and sorting

Answer (score -1):

You can create an add-in which recursively iterates over all subsites and collects all items of all lists in these subsites which use the particular content type you want to roll up. If all lists have the same name you can simply select by name. The collected list items can be written in a separate list in the root site.

You might try this add-in from the SharePoint store: [List Aggregator Content Roll Up](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380549)